# Python & Matplotlib: creating a chart first and showing it at a second moment

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm working on a project implemented in Python 2.7 with a GUI made with PyQt4. I am trying to create a chart with Matplotlib that will be created while the main thread is running but that should be shown only when the user press on a certain button. The idea is:

```
def makeTheChart(self, equitycurve):
            ecchart.plot(equitycurve)
```

This first method will be called from another class (that instatiates the object and passes the data "equitycurve" to it; the chart "ecchart" is then ready (if I would put a ecchart.show() right after it shows me the right chart);

```
def showTheChart(self):
            ecchart.show(block=True)
```

The second method, instead, should be called when pressing a button on the GUI. So the problem is: 
the chart is created (cause if I write "ecchart.show()" into the first function I'm gonna get the right one) but when I press on the button to call "ecchart.show()" I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\BackTest.py", line 5496, in showTheChart
    ecchart.show(block=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 143, in show
    _show(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 82, in __call__
    manager.show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 576, in show
    self.canvas.draw_idle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 367, in draw_idle
    self._idle_callback = self._tkcanvas.after_idle(idle_draw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 509, in after_idle
    return self.after('idle', func, *args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 502, in after
    return self.tk.call('after', ms, name)
_tkinter.TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

Any idea about what the problem could depend on and how to fix it? Thanks, don't hesitate ask more questions if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would suggest first check [{this}](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) for working example of embedding `matplotlib` charts in `Qt4`. Also you may find it useful check [{this link}](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib) where there are many working other examples.

Shortly, you may try to make invisibile your chart by using `youchart.axes.set_visible(False)` when you're creating it then you will be able latter to set it visible, i.e., `yourchart.axes.set_visible(True)`. We tried this method in the example given at first link above and it worked as supposed.